# jQuery filter table with counting results

Tags: jquery, filter

I found somewere here solution how to filter the table. I tried to modify it and add statement in case no results found and i did it - but - 
when i long keep backspace to delete all value from input or put number to input and then i delete it the statement is still visible. 
Anybody know how to fix it ?

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
    //split the current value of searchInput
    var data = this.value.split(" ");
    //create a jquery object of the rows
    var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
    if (this.value == "") {
        jo.show();
        return;
    }
    //hide all the rows
    jo.hide();

    //Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
   var x = jo.filter(function (i, v) {
        var $t = $(this);
        for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
            if ($t.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(data[d].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    })
    //show the rows that match.
    .show().length;

        if(x == 0) {
        $('table').find('tfoot > tr > td').html('no results');
    } else {
         $('table').find('tfoot > tr > td').html('test');
    }
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
    $(this).css({
        "color": "black"
    });
    $(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
    "color": "#C0C0C0"
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z83a9fxy/)

Answer (score 0):

You use .keyup for searchInput. That means when u hold backspace that it won't run until you release backspace. Using .keydown with the same code as .keyup could fix that issue.

So make a second binding for .keydown.

Also your code won't run on copy,paste,cut from mouse. See these bindings to make it work http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-detect-copy-paste-and-cut-behavior-with-jquery/